# Compiling in Visual C++ 2005

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I wrote a C++ DLL and it has been compiled. It requires Visual C++ 2010. How can I compile it for Visual C++ 2005, and will it work for Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7?

My DLL uses detours 1.5 and windows sockets. I use Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I hope my edit... makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to install Visual C++ 2005 on the same machine, and read this article:

http://weblogs.asp.net/israelio/archive/2009/10/20/enable-vs-2010-multi-targeting-also-for-vs2005-c.aspx

(I have used multi targeting of VS 2010 only for the VS 2008 tool chain, but with the patch above it should work in a similar manner).

Comment: i added this patch for my Visual Studio 2010, have setted v80 platform, but now errors like cant find <stdio.h>, how can i fix that?

Comment: Do you have VS 2005 installed? Did you set include paths correctly (to the folders below the VS 2005 installation folder)? Please check that first.